# How to match a part of an <iframe> tag?

Tags: php, html, regex, match

I'm trying to match the highlighted parts of this string:

```
<iframe maybe something here src="http://some.random.url.com/" and the string continues...
```

I need to match the src="" if it's placed inside of an  tag. The iframe tag can be placed anywhere in the source.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 14):

You should use a DOM parser for that. Here's an example with DOMDocument :

```
<?php
    $document = new DOMDocument();
    $document->loadHTML(file_get_contents('yourFileNameHere.html'));
    $lst = $document->getElementsByTagName('iframe');

    for ($i=0; $i<$lst->length; $i++) {
        $iframe= $lst->item($i);
        echo $iframe->attributes->getNamedItem('src')->value, '<br />';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why is using a DOM parser better than just preg_matching out the part that i want? It seems simpler just to write one for it all instead? Apparently this is better for some reason, cause it's already gotten 5 thumbs up, hehe...

Comment: @Nike because [HTML is not regular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). HTML can be broken, attributes can contain characters that you are expecting to find at the end of a tag, tags can be nested... all of that makes regular expressions a bad tool for parsing HTML.

Comment: @Nike If you just use a regex, you might match an `<iframe ...` tag inside of a comment, or your regex might not handle some characters that could appear between the `<iframe` and the `src=` tag, or you might get the delimiters wrong at the end of the `src` attribute (attributes might not be quoted), and you'll have to do HTML entity decoding on the contents of the `src` attribute yourself if you use a regex, and on and on. By the time you handle all of these cases in a regex, it will be longer, more complicated, and much more likely to be buggy, than just using a DOM parser.

Comment: @Nick Just consider this example : <!--<iframe src="-->NotAPath"> How can regexp effectively recognize it's not an iframe ?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$html='<iframe maybe somethin gere src="http://some.random.url.com/" and blablabla';

preg_match('|<iframe [^>]*(src="[^"]+")[^>]*|', $html, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(75) "<iframe maybe somethin gere src="http://some.random.url.com/" and blablabla"
  [1]=>
  string(33) "src="http://some.random.url.com/""
}
```

But this is a quick way to do this using regular expression, which may break with unclean html or cause problems, go for a dom parser for a good proof solution.

Answer (score 2):

If youre source is well formed xml you can also use xpath to find the string.

```
<?php
  $file = simplexml_load_file("file.html");
  $result = $file->xpath("//iframe[@src]/@src");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression is going to be the cleanest way to do it:

```
preg_match('<iframe.+?src="(.+?)".+?<\/iframe>', $iframe);

print_r($iframe);

array([0] => whole reg ex match, [1] => your src url);
```

Comment: Probably downvoted because it's not recommended to parse HTML using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a DOM parser, but this regex would get you started if there is a reason you must use regexes

```
.*(?<iframeOpening><iframe)\s[^>]*(?<iframeSrc>src=['"][^>'"]+['"]?).*
```

It uses named capture groups by the way, here's how they work

```
preg_match('/.*(?<iframeOpening><iframe)\s[^>]*src=[\'"](?<iframeSrc>[^>\'"])+[\'"]?.*/', $searchText, $groups);
print_r($groups['iframeSrc']);
```

Comment: Sorry if i was unclear. That matches the entire iframe element, but i only want to match the SRC of the iframe. :)

Comment: @Nike, you weren't unclear, and this doesn't match the entire iframe element, well, it does, but it includes named groups so you can retrieve the src, see my modified answer

Comment: We're getting closer, but this is what it returns now: src="http://existenz.se/amedia/?typ=youtube&url=http://www.youtube.com/v/yTJpd57jLiY " marginheight="0"..... But i only want to return the actual value of the src tag (not src="..").

Comment: @Nike, try it now, I modified it slightly

Comment: Got an error now: Warning:  preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 70 in....

Comment: I got it working! :) I removed the second * at the end, and now i only get the SRC of it. Is there any way to remove the src= and the quotes around the url? Thanks!

Comment: @Nike, that extra `*` was a typo.  I changed it to only return the contents of the src attribute.  You did suggest you wanted the src included in your question though, which is why I had it returned.

Comment: @Nike You can add a new capture group around the inside of the quotes. Change this: `[\'"][^>\'"]+[\'"]` to this: `[\'"](?<srcContents>[^>\'"]+)[\'"]`. But I strongly recommend against doing this, and recommend just using the DOM parser mentioned above, as you will have many bugs if you use this regex to try and extract the `src` from your `iframe` tags (for example: `<iframe class="src=" src="...">` or `<iframe src="http://example.com/query?foo=bar&amp;baz=quux">` which needs decoding before you will get the actual URL).

Comment: I'm probably going to change to using a DOM parser later, but right now i know what the URL's are going to be (mostly), and i also know how the source code of the webpage looks like, so it will (hopefully) work as it should for the moment, until something changes. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @Brian Campbell, I fully agree, DOM is almost always the best approach... but depending on the situation, it's not always.

Answer (score 1):

see [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

That said, your particular situation isn't really parsing... just string matching.
Methods for that have already been enumerated before my answer here...

Comment: I'm waiting to be disappointed whenever I enter this kind of question expecting a post that links to that answer :)

Comment: well, we work hard to spread the Tales of the Regex Dom Parser, and Its Demise :D