# PHP: regular expression to find out and retrieve values from xml attributes

Tags: php, xml

How can I write a regular expression to retrieve values from xml node?
Actually the node structure is very big. So we can't traverse easily, so I want to read as normal text file and hope I can write a regex to find out the matching elements.

```
<node1>
 <node2>str</node2>
 <node3>Text</node3>
 <myvalue>Here is the values string..</myvalue>
</node1>
```

The above is the pattern I want to retrieve values `<myvalue></myvalue>` but in my xml there are so many other node contains the `<myvalue>` child. So only way to find out the appropriate node which I want is in the above pattern. The only change in  value rest of the node values are same `<node2>str</node2>`, `<node3>Text</node3>` are always same.

So how can I write the regex for php?

Comment: Show a real example of the XML document, including the problematic areas (many `myvalue` nodes, complex structure, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Use a XML parser, Regex is not appropriate to do that kind of parsing.

Here's the list of the XML parser you can use :

- [XMLReader](http://ca.php.net/manual/fr/book.xmlreader.php)
- [DOM](http://ca.php.net/manual/fr/book.dom.php) ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636365/how-to-match-a-part-of-an-iframe-tag/3636391#3636391))
- [Simple XML](http://ca.php.net/manual/fr/book.simplexml.php) ([Example](http://tuxradar.com/practicalphp/12/3/3) posted by [Fanis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137259/fanis))

Here's a simple example with DOM that will find all the `myvalue` located in the `node1`.

```
<?php
    $document = new DOMDocument();
    $document->loadXML(
        '<all>
            <myvalue>Elsewhere</myvalue>
            <node1>
                <node2>str</node2>
                <node3>Text</node3>
                <myvalue>Here is the values string..</myvalue>
            </node1>
        </all>');
    $lst = $document->getElementsByTagName('node1');

    for ($i=0; $i<$lst->length; $i++) {
        $node1= $lst->item($i);
        $myvalue = $node1->getElementsByTagName('myvalue');

        if ($myvalue->length > 0) {
            echo $myvalue->item(0)->textContent;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: but finding that node is bit difficult task.. that is why i prefer regx

Comment: @coderex It is easier and you sure to get accurate result everytime.

Comment: @coderex you can use XPath to search through the XML once you parse it, for example with SimpleXML: http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/12/3/3

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a SAX-based XML parser which will let you use a real XML parser without storing an entire DOM tree in memory.  [XMLReader](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) lets you parse the file without even reading the entire file into memory.  Using regex to dig into XML is going to be painful.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using regular expression for this, try

```
preg_match_all('<myvalue>([\s\S]+)<\/myvalue>', $text, $matches);
```

Comment: but i need to check this also

Comment: preg_match_all('<node2>str<\/node2><node3>Text<\/node3><myvalue>([\s\S]+)<\/myvalue>' $text, $matches);

Comment: but in xml each node have a new line char , it think, so my try fails in this case. so now i need to remove the space an newlines chars